# ERROR while plotting prices against Dates using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning

Below is my code:

```
`date = pt['date']   # date is of datetime.date type
prices = pt[target_col].astype(str)     # pt[target_col] initially returns floating point values

# # prices = tuple(pt[target_col])
# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

plt.xlim([start_date, end_date+timedelta(days=30)])
plt.ylim([max(df_max, f_max), min(df_min, f_min)])
prices = pt.sort_values('date')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

# I am trying to plot the actual prices of a stock, overlapped by my test data output and finally
# extended by my prediction of future values

plt.plot_date(date, prices, color='blue', label='Actual Stock Prices')
plt.plot(date[-len(y_pred_scaled):], y_pred_scaled, color='red', label='Predicted Stock Prices on Test Data')
plt.plot_date(future_dates, future_prices, color='yellow', label='Future Prices')

plt.title("Prices of Stocks (Apple)")
plt.xlabel("Dates")
plt.ylabel("Prices")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()`
```

I am receiving this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 17
     14 prices = pt.sort_values('date')
     15 plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
---> 17 plt.plot_date(date, prices, color='blue', label='Actual Stock Prices')
     18 plt.plot(date[-len(y_pred_scaled):], y_pred_scaled, color='red', label='Predicted Stock Prices on Test Data')
     19 plt.plot_date(future_dates, future_prices, color='yellow', label='Future Prices')

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2795, in plot_date(x, y, fmt, tz, xdate, ydate, data, **kwargs)
   2791 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot_date)
   2792 def plot_date(
   2793         x, y, fmt='o', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, *,
   2794         data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2795     return gca().plot_date(
   2796         x, y, fmt=fmt, tz=tz, xdate=xdate, ydate=ydate,
   2797         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1442, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1439 @functools.wraps(func)
   1440 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1441     if data is None:
-> 1442         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1444     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1446                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1776, in Axes.plot_date(self, x, y, fmt, tz, xdate, ydate, **kwargs)
   1774 if ydate:
   1775     self.yaxis_date(tz)
-> 1776 return self.plot(x, y, fmt, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1688, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445 """
   1446 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1447 
   (...)
   1685 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1686 """
   1687 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1688 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1689 for line in lines:
   1690     self.add_line(line)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:311, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    309     this += args[0],
    310     args = args[1:]
--> 311 yield from self._plot_args(
    312     this, kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey=ambiguous_fmt_datakey)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:501, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey)
    499     self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
    500 if self.axes.yaxis is not None:
--> 501     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    503 if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    504     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    505                      f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:1670, in Axis.update_units(self, data)
   1668 neednew = self.converter != converter
   1669 self.converter = converter
-> 1670 default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1671 if default is not None and self.units is None:
   1672     self.set_units(default)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:105, in StrCategoryConverter.default_units(data, axis)
    103 # the conversion call stack is default_units -> axis_info -> convert
    104 if axis.units is None:
--> 105     axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
    106 else:
    107     axis.units.update(data)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:181, in UnitData.__init__(self, data)
    179 self._counter = itertools.count()
    180 if data is not None:
--> 181     self.update(data)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:214, in UnitData.update(self, data)
    212 # check if convertible to number:
    213 convertible = True
--> 214 for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
    215     # OrderedDict just iterates over unique values in data.
    216     _api.check_isinstance((str, bytes), value=val)
    217     if convertible:
    218         # this will only be called so long as convertible is True.

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So basically, I am here trying to show the outputs of my model on test data (y_test) and based on the training it has received, I want to further depict the prices of a stock for the next 30 days.

I tried converting every array that needs to be plot into a string datatype but somehow I end up receiving a similar error.

Any Suggestions?